# How to change a bootstrap selector default placeholder text colour

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to change the default placeholder of a disabled option from the default black. to #008752.

Code example below:

```
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <select class="form-control" size="auto" id="selectpicker1" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Please select...</option>
          <option value="opt01">opt1</option>
          <option value="opt02">opt2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

The line of code that needs to be changed:

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Please select...</option>
```

Example of the correct colour below, from the two date inputs, with the slectpicker in its default colour.

[image]

The following code below is also not working:

```
 <option value="" style="color:#008752 !important" disabled selected>Please select...</option>
```

It changes the wrong text line and not the placeholder.

[image]

Just tried the webkit example and it just replaced the other placeholders and not the sector

```
.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #008752 !important;
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #008752 !important;
}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #008752 !important;
}
```

[image]

Outcome of webkit test

Comment: Can you explain what you need more clearly?

Comment: Change the colour of the Please select... text to #008752

Comment: I too had same issue...this is what I did http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/BqhlD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself by trying:

```
<select class="form-control" size="auto" style="color: #008752" id="selectpicker1" required>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick.

```
 ::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
        color:  #008752;
    }
    :-moz-placeholder {
       color:  #008752;
       opacity:  1;
    }
    ::-moz-placeholder {
       color:   #008752;
       opacity:  1;
    }
    :-ms-input-placeholder {
       color:   #008752;
    }
```

Comment: Try to check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css - There are huge post about this. I believe it should be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean changing "Please select..." to this color? If that's what you want then you could try it with these:

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('selectpicker1').options[0].style.color = '#008752';
```

HTML (inline css)

```
 <option value="" style="color:#008752" disabled selected>Please select...</option>
```

There are more and efficient ways, but these take the cake.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    .form-control #disabledtext {
          color : #008752 !important;
    }
</style>
```

use id="disabledtext"

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
      <select class="form-control" size="auto" id="selectpicker1" required>
      <option id="disabledtext" value="" disabled selected>Please select...</option>
      <option value="opt01">opt1</option>
      <option value="opt02">opt2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can also use inline css like `<option style="color: #008752 !important;" id="disabledtext" value="" disabled selected>Please select...</option>`

Answer (score 1):

This is fragment form `bootstrap.css`:

```
.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}
```

So try to change values and add `!important` to them:

```
.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #008752 !important;
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #008752 !important;
}
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #008752 !important;
}
```